# How to retrieve items based on linked items from Contentful?

Tags: contentful

I have two content models in Contentful, an "Article" and a "Tag". Articles have a one-to-many relationship with tags. Is it possible using either the Contentful REST or GraphQL APIs to fetch articles based on multiple related tags?

Below is a cURL request taken from their [documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/links/links-to-a-specific-item) that demonstrates a way in which items can be retreived via a **single** related item.

```sh
curl --request GET "https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/$SPACE\
/environments/$ENVIRONMENT/entries\
?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN\
&links_to_entry=$PRIMARY_ENTRY_ID"
```

My immediate thinking to retrieve items based on **multiple** related items was doing:

```sh
curl --request GET "https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/$SPACE\
/environments/$ENVIRONMENT/entries\
?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN\
&links_to_entry=$PRIMARY_ENTRY_ID,$SECONDARY_ENTRY_ID"
```

This results in an error stating that multiple values for a filter CANNOT be used. Is there another way to accomplish this? If so, can someone provide an example using the REST and GraphQL APIs?

Thoughts, suggestions and/or solutions appreciated!

Comment: Hey, i don't think there will be any option to get result based on multiple links to entry,
what you can do is get result for 2 queries and loop through data and filter common data to new variable.